# How can I change color of an svg attached to an img tag in html but only using css and no javascript?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to attach an svg to an img tag like so

```
<img src="./img/home.svg" class="svg home-img" alt="Image of home">
```

From looking around the forums and guides I found out that you can use javascript to convert this img tag into an inline svg tag and then you'll be able to alter it like that.

I can not have javascript in my project. How can I go about doing this? This is the svg file I am working with.

```
<svg version="1.0" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 48 48" enable-background="new 0 0 48 48" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#E8EAF6" points="42,39 6,39 6,23 24,6 42,23 "/>
<g>
    <polygon fill="#C5CAE9" points="39,21 34,16 34,9 39,9   "/>
    <rect x="6" y="39" fill="#C5CAE9" width="36" height="5"/>
</g>
<polygon fill="#B71C1C" points="24,4.3 4,22.9 6,25.1 24,8.4 42,25.1 44,22.9 "/>
<rect x="18" y="28" fill="#D84315" width="12" height="16"/>
<rect x="21" y="17" fill="#01579B" width="6" height="6"/>
<path fill="#FF8A65" d="M27.5,35.5c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5v2c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5S28,38.3,28,38v-2C28,35.7,27.8,35.5,27.5,35.5z"
    />
</svg>
```

Comment: do you have to have an img tag? You can place the svg code directly into your html and alter it from there.

Comment: I know but I would rather have an img tag so I don't have to keep adding a long svg everytime I want it to appear. I guess that may be the only way though.

Comment: You simply can't convert from `img` to inline svg without javascript trickery. If you are using a server side templating system use a partial, otherwise just place the code inline.